# ProtoBuf-Net Compression of already compressed?

Tags: protobuf-net

How would protocol buffer handle compression of an already compressed byte[]?

Pseudo example:

```
[ProtoContract]
class Foo
{
  [ProtoMember(1)]
  public string Bar{ get; set; }

  [ProtoMember(2)]
  public byte[] CompressedFoo { get; set; }
}


// proto is my ProtocolBuffer.Net utility class

Foo _foo = new Foo() { Bar = "Hello World"; };

Foo _foo2 = new Foo() { Bar = "Goodbye cruel world"; };
_foo2.CompressedFoo = proto.Compress(_foo);

byte[] compressedFoo2 = proto.Compress(_foo2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The protobuf specification does not include ***any*** compression, unless you count the `varint` encoding of integer data. A `byte[]` in C# is treated as the *protobuf* `bytes` type, which means it is simply a length-prefixed raw dump of the bytes. So if `CompressedFoo` is (just as an example) 12 bytes, it will serialize it in 14 bytes, made up of:

- 1 byte for the data-type (`2`, to indicate length-prefixed) and field number (`2`, from the `[ProtoMember(2)]`), mashed ("shifted") together and varint encoded
- 1 byte for the length of the data (`12`), varint encoded
- 12 bytes for the data (taken "as is" from `CompressedFoo`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I have asked another question on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719169/protobuf-net-performance